# Implement a semantic web search engine using Arabic wordnet

Tags: web-applications, arabic, wordnet

I want to develop a web application that will use the current AWN, and provide the user to obtain semantic results. What I require are the things that I need to know before going into implementation of the system. My purpose is to do semantic search in the Holy Quran. Any help will be appreciated in this regard.

Comment: Insteading of asking help. You shall try with some attempt and ask for the errors you meet. This is really off-topic to ask the code or suggestion in stackoverflow

Comment: By "Things that I need to know" I meant the books or research papers that might help me in grabbing the concepts of semantic search in general, code was never required just some expert advice.

Comment: You mean something like to search and display the items ?

Comment: Yes that is how the interface is going to be, I am asking for some useful stuff to read like a book or previous work in this regard.

Comment: You plan to implement in web ?

Comment: Yes I want to implement it as a web application.

Comment: Cool, Then i suggest you to use php-mysqli with jquery-ajax calls.You want to know how to do that by giving some example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some workouts to achieve it

**Step 1 :**

Create a Table which has all possible words

**Step 2 :**

Create a php file and get your input

**Step 3 :**

Pass your input to the server page or another page which will compare your input with the matches

**Step 4 :**

Find atlest 2 matches and show the output

**Ajax Call :**

```
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});
```

**Query to be processed**

**"select * from quote where word like '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 2"**

Here `$q` is the input you give

I have created a demo for you which have the possible words like 
 `Alhamdh, Bayan, Allah, Sunnah, Khalifa`

Here is the [Demo for you](http://sysaxiom.com/test/aliniaz/)

The image which comes near dropdown is just for style and you can change it later on :)